# C# LINQ to XML: "Safe" enum value from an XElement?

Tags: c#, linq, enums

To get a "safe" integer value from an XElement in C# one can use a method like

```
    public int GetIntegerValue(XElement x, string tag)
    {
        int result  = Int32.MinValue;
        if (x.Element(tag) != null)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(x.Element(tag).Value, out result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The code returns the correct integer value if the element is present and contains a parseable string, otherwise Int32.MinValue. This approach would function with a few other common types like double, bool, etc., but what about enum?

Can there also be a function like GetEnumValue(XElement x, string tag, Type enumType) or GetEnumValue(XElement x, string tag, TEnum defaultValue) or alike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following method:

```
public static TEnum GetEnumValue<TEnum>(XElement x, string tag)
    where TEnum : struct
{
    // Set default value
    TEnum parsedEnum = default(TEnum);

    var element = x.Element(tag);
    if(element != null)
    {
        // Try to parse
        Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(element.Value, out parsedEnum);
    }

    return parsedEnum;
}
```

And then call it like:

```
CarType carType = GetEnumValue<CarType>(xElement, tag);
```

Comment: Thanks Adil, it functions!

Comment: @AlexKonnen, I am glad that it helped. But do not forget to accept as answer it it works for you

Comment: Adil, I would eagerly do it, just tell me how (I could not send an email to you)

Comment: @AlexKonnen, have look at to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/283995) at meta

Comment: Thanks Adil, now I do know. Any idea why my reputation diminished after this question? Was it so silly?

Comment: Oh! It got bigger again! What a funny game!

Comment: @AlexKonnen, it diminished becouse your question was downvoted (-2), and it increased again, beacuse you accepted answer (+2). Read about repurtation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

You can CAST an ENUM to an integer.  Also you can use the .ToString() to help Identify the enum types.

Try this code below - it is very quick, but it does work.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public enum testTypes { test1, test2, test3};


    private static testTypes GetEnumValue(XElement x, string tag)
    {
        if (x.Element(tag)!=null) {
            var v = x.Element(tag).Value.ToString();
            var testEnums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(testTypes));
            foreach (testTypes enumType in testEnums) {
                if (v.Equals((testTypes) enumType)) return enumType;
            }
        }
        return (testTypes) 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        XElement x = new XElement("MyType","Test1");
        var EnumVal = GetEnumValue(x, "MyType");    
        Console.WriteLine("Type is {0}",(testTypes) EnumVal);

    }
}
```

You could actually use Generics to generalise the approach instead of using the static Method.

Answer (score 1):

Working with previous Adil, one can also create an extension function as follow :

```
public static TEnum ToEnumValue<TEnum>(this XElement xelem)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        if (xelem is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(xelem));
        }

        Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(xelem.Value, out TEnum parsedEnum);
        return parsedEnum;
    }
```

then it can be used as follow :

```
MyViewModel.Mode = node.Element("MyMode")?.ToEnumValue<ModeEnum>() ?? ModeEnum.Mode1;
```